# VBA Offseting Copying Range not working

Tags: excel, vba

I have the same code as this in other pages and it works fine but in one page its not offseting the paste to the 3rd line, its only doing it to the 1st line can someone help please?

```
Set wsInfoFrom = Worksheets("STP1st")
Set wsInfoTo = Worksheets("StowToPrime")
lastrow = wsInfoFrom.Range("B" & wsInfoFrom.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set copyRange = wsInfoFrom.Range("B5:B" & lastrow)

wsInfoTo.Range("A1:A9999" & lastrow).ClearContents

    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy wsInfoTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0)
```

Comment: when i test it in the VB builder it works fine but when i run the macro it moves the rows up for column A

Comment: (a) I can't see how `wsInfoTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0)` can point to anything higher than cell A4 (b) I can't see how `wsInfoTo.Range("A1:A9999" & lastrow).ClearContents` will work - e.g. if `lastrow` was 123 (because B123 was the last occupied cell in `wsInfoFrom`) you would be trying to clear the contents of `A1:A9999123` - I therefore suspect that crashes if you have anything below B99 in `wsInfoFrom`.

Comment: Apologizes the code there is fine i've debugged it to another piece of code that is removing duplicates from the row later on. I need to do this Columns(1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1) but from Cell A3 down

Comment: Does `Range(Cells(3, "A"), Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1)` work?

Comment: Your code is perfect and just remove 9999 from the above code since it is not at all required when you are referring & lastrow.

Answer (score 0):

Try the slightly modifed and more organized code below, I think this is what you meant to do:

```
Set wsInfoFrom = Worksheets("STP1st")
Set wsInfoTo = Worksheets("StowToPrime")

With wsInfoFrom
    lastrow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set copyRange = .Range("B5:B" & lastrow)
End With

With wsInfoTo
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row ' <-- different last row in this sheet
    .Range("A1:A" & lastrow).ClearContents

    copyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(3, 0)
End With
```